# pyspark - rename dots in nested columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I read a nested json into a df so I have structs/arrays few levels deep. some nested cols have name like "Kafka.blob" which I want to rename to Kafka_blob. i can't find a way to rename this col at deep level of the schema

initial schema looks like:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Client: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- Vl1: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Vl2: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Prch: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Vl3: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Detail: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Vl4: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Bs: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Kafka.blob: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Vl6: string (nullable = true)
```

desired schema:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Client: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- Vl1: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Vl2: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Prch: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Vl3: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Detail: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Vl4: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Bs: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- kafka_blob: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Vl6: string (nullable = true)
```

note that when I initially read the json I don't provide schema. so I don't want to hardcode providing a schema, just want to replace on whatever schema I get from reading the json

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `df.printSchema` and also add the schema that you would like to have as output (with the column renamed)?

Comment: @Koedlt I have updated

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically change the names of the fields in your schema (without having a predefined schema) by using the `schema.simpleString()` method. Consider the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import re

# Not needed for you, just creating a dataframe with a specific schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("SOMECAPITALIZEDFIELD", StringType(), True),
    StructField("array",
        ArrayType(
            StructType([
                StructField("Kafka.blob", StringType(), True),
                StructField("nested_struct", StructType([
                    StructField("nested.STRing", StringType(), True),
                ]), True),
            ])
        )
    )
])

# Creating the df here
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(
        {"SOMECAPITALIZEDFIELD": "someString"},
        [{"Kafka.blob": "anotherString", "nested_struct": {"nested.STRing": "lol"}}]
    )],
    schema = schema
)

df.printSchema()
root                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 |-- SOMECAPITALIZEDFIELD: string (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 |-- array: array (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 |    |    |-- Kafka.blob: string (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 |    |    |-- nested_struct: struct (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 |    |    |    |-- nested.STRing: string (nullable = true)

# Function used by re.sub to substitute strings. Now it transforms column names
# in lowercase, and replaces "." characters by "_"
def subsituteString(match):
    return match.group(0).lower().replace(".", "_")

# Function that transforms a schema into the new schema
def lowerCaseAndRemoveDots(schema):
    output = re.sub(r"<[\w.]+:", subsituteString, schema.simpleString())
    return output

# Creating a new df with the columns renamed following the
# lowerCaseAndRemoveDots function
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, lowerCaseAndRemoveDots(df.schema))

df2.printSchema()
root                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 |-- somecapitalizedfield: string (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 |-- array: array (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 |    |    |-- kafka_blob: string (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 |    |    |-- nested_struct: struct (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 |    |    |    |-- nested_string: string (nullable = true)
```

As you can see, the idea is that we transform the `schema.simpleString()` value, that looks like this:

```
'struct<SOMECAPITALIZEDFIELD:string,array:array<struct<Kafka.blob:string,nested_struct:struct<nested.STRing:string>>>>'
```

into this:

```
'struct<somecapitalizedfield:string,array:array<struct<kafka_blob:string,nested_struct:struct<nested_string:string>>>>'
```

with simple regex substitution. At the end we create `df2` with this new schema.

Hope this helps!

Comment: problem is this involves hardcoding column names like array and Kafka_blob. also does not go to deeper nested level

Comment: It goes as deep as you want: you just need to adapt your `renamedArraySchema` to contain extra `StructType` levels. I'll adapt my answer to show that.

Comment: And if you want to rename the `Kafka.blob` column to `Kafka_blob`, you need to write that somewhere right? How else would you communicate to Spark which exact field needs to change names?

Comment: I just want to say replace _ with . and lowercase, but in totally generic way

Comment: Ahhhh but that is a totally different question! Maybe you should edit your question then to specify that.

Comment: @tooptoop4 is this more what you're looking for?

Comment: schema = what would I set this to without hardcoding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250628/discussion-between-koedlt-and-tooptoop4).

Comment: this doesn't handle when field is not first thing after < ....ie struct<allowed:string,connect.decimal.precision:string

Comment: That's just a question of changing the regex pattern. But you're posing a different question through the comments for the second time now. Please make a separate question post about your current issue and we can have a look at it :)